# uv_textures.active.data[0].uv equivalent in Blender 2.7?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I'm trying to update a 3rd party addon from Blender 2.6 to 2.7, as the author won't do it.
The only problem I have is here:

```
ActiveUV = BMesh.data.uv_textures.active
for iFace, BFace in enumerate( BMesh.data.polygons ):
    FaceUVs = []

    if ActiveUV != None:
        for UV in ActiveUV.data[iFace].uv:
            FaceUVs.append( [UV[0], UV[1]] )
```

And I have this error message:

> 'MeshTexturePoly' object has no attribute 'uv'

I've tried with:

```
BMesh.data.tessface_uv_textures.active
```

But it returns 'None'

And with:

```
BMesh.data.uv_layers.active
```

But It doesn't seem to be the right one.

Comment: What mode is your object in? `len(ob.data.uv_layers.active.data)` is always 0 in *Edit Mode*, you need to be in *Object Mode* to access it. For `tessface_*` attributes, it is required to call `Mesh.calc_tessface()` beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found a solution, maybe not the optimum one, but it works:

```
for iFace, BFace in enumerate( BMesh.data.polygons ):
    FaceUVs = []

    for i in BFace.loop_indices: # <-- python Range object with the proper indices already set.
        l = BMesh.data.loops[i] # The loop entry this polygon point refers to.
        for j,ul in enumerate(BMesh.data.uv_layers):
            FaceUVs.append( [ul.data[l.index].uv[0], ul.data[l.index].uv[1]] )
```